# Multible rows at one row on the ActiveAdmin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

We are using ActiveAdmin gem and display all revenues from a revenue-table.

Every entry on that revenue-table has a transaction-id. Every transaction has minimum two revenues-entries on that revenue-table.

Now we want to display all revenues from one transaction-id at only one row (at the index-page). Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create an ActiveAdmin.register for that **Transactions-** and not for the **Revenues-** table.

So we are able to add a "table_for" element containing all sub-rows.

```
ActiveAdmin.register CreditTransaction
  index do
    column :id
    ...
    column "Stack" do |ct|
      rv = Revenue.where(credit_transaction_id: ct.id)

      table_for rv.order(params[:order].gsub('_', ' ')) do |revenue|
        column "#" do |ct|
          ct.subid
        end
        ...
        column :created_at
      end

    end
  end
end
```

[image]